# How Can I write in my code to exclude accounts that have had a payment posted w/in last 45 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server Mgmt Studio and I'm trying to identify accounts that have not had a payment posted since the last 45 days.  I've tried declaring a min and max date with getdate being less than 45 days, but that didnt work.  I've also tried stating "where last payment !> getdate() -45".... but this did not give me the results I was looking for.  what I need the query to do is only identify accounts that truly have not had a payment post in the last 45 days.  but I'm not sure how to state this in my where clause.  Here's my query

```sql
DECLARE @minDate datetime;
DECLARE @maxDate datetime;
SET @minDate = GETDATE();
SET @maxDate = GETDATE() - 45;

SELECT DISTINCT
       a.id,
       a.FacilityCode AS [Facility],
       a.accountUnit,
       a.accountNum AS [Account Number],
       a.amountBalance AS [Balance],
       a.accountstatus AS [Status],
       CONVERT(date, a.accountStatusDate) AS StatusDate,
       pmtEntryDate AS [Pmt Entry Date],
       v.LastLinkARpmtDate AS [Last Pmt Date],
       CONVERT(date, a.accountnextactdate) AS NextActionDate,
       CONVERT(date, a.rpcDate) AS RightpartyContactDate,
       a.flag AS accountFlag,
       pay.flag AS pmtFlag,
       a.accounttype
FROM dbo.tbAccount a
    JOIN dbo.tbpmtinfo pay ON a.id = pay.id
    JOIN dbo.vLastPmtDate v ON v.id = a.id
    FULL JOIN (SELECT id,
                      MAX(deDate) AS MFSLoadDate
               FROM dbo.tbDataEvents (NOLOCK)
               WHERE deNewVal = 'MFS'
               GROUP BY id) m ON m.id = a.id
WHERE pay.flag IN ('D')
  AND a.amountBalance > 0
  AND a.FacilityCode IN ('PHKY', 'QANM', 'QAOH', 'QBCA', 'QBIL', 'QBTX', 'QCIL', 'QDAL', 'QEWY', 'QFAR', 'QFGA',
                         'QGIL', 'QHAR', 'QHIL', 'QHTN', 'QLAL', 'QLPA', 'QMIL', 'QMNC', 'QMNM', 'QMNV', 'QMOR',
                         'QMTN', 'QMTX', 'QMUT', 'QRIL', 'QRKY', 'QSPA', 'QTGA', 'QTKY', 'QUIL', 'QVIL', 'QWIL', 'LHFL')
  AND a.amountBalance >= '1000'
  AND a.accountStatus IN ('PA', 'PP', 'BPA')
  AND a.flag = 'A'
  AND a.accountType IN ('Resid', 'Slfpy')
  --and LastLinkARpmtDate !> Getdate() -45 and accountNum = '40728597'
  AND LastLinkARpmtDate BETWEEN @minDate AND @maxDate;
```

Comment: I really suggest you get in the habit of formatting your SQL well; such as using line breaks and white space well. It makes your SQL *Far* more readable.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if it is needed and the implications understood and accepted, AT LEAST use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: `LastLinkARpmtDate BETWEEN @minDate AND @maxDate;` Look closer. What value did you assign to minDate?

Comment: And you effectively want to include accounts whose last payment date was before <today - 45 days>. Does that make things more clear? Assuming, of course, that particular column is the one you need to filter on.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause to eliminate recent activity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
    ,a.FacilityCode [Facility]
    ,a.accountUnit
    ,a.accountNum [Account Number]
    ,a.amountBalance [Balance]
    ,a.accountstatus [Status]
    ,convert(DATE, a.accountStatusDate) StatusDate
    ,pmtEntryDate [Pmt Entry Date]
    ,v.LastLinkARpmtDate [Last Pmt Date]
    ,convert(DATE, a.accountnextactdate) NextActionDate
    ,convert(DATE, a.rpcDate) RightpartyContactDate
    ,a.flag AS accountFlag
    ,pay.flag AS pmtFlag
    ,a.accounttype
FROM dbo.tbAccount AS a
JOIN dbo.tbpmtinfo AS pay ON a.id = pay.id
JOIN dbo.vLastPmtDate AS v ON v.id = a.id
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT id
        ,Max(deDate) AS MFSLoadDate
    FROM dbo.tbDataEvents(NOLOCK)
    WHERE deNewVal = 'MFS'
    GROUP BY id
    ) m ON m.id = a.id
WHERE pay.flag IN ('D')
    AND a.amountBalance > 0
    AND a.FacilityCode IN (
        'PHKY'
        ,'QANM'
        ,'QAOH'
        ,'QBCA'
        ,'QBIL'
        ,'QBTX'
        ,'QCIL'
        ,'QDAL'
        ,'QEWY'
        ,'QFAR'
        ,'QFGA'
        ,'QGIL'
        ,'QHAR'
        ,'QHIL'
        ,'QHTN'
        ,'QLAL'
        ,'QLPA'
        ,'QMIL'
        ,'QMNC'
        ,'QMNM'
        ,'QMNV'
        ,'QMOR'
        ,'QMTN'
        ,'QMTX'
        ,'QMUT'
        ,'QRIL'
        ,'QRKY'
        ,'QSPA'
        ,'QTGA'
        ,'QTKY'
        ,'QUIL'
        ,'QVIL'
        ,'QWIL'
        ,'LHFL'
        )
    AND a.amountBalance >= '1000'
    AND a.accountStatus IN (
        'PA'
        ,'PP'
        ,'BPA'
        )
    AND a.flag = 'A'
    AND a.accountType IN (
        'Resid'
        ,'Slfpy'
        )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM vLastPmtDate
        WHERE v.id = a.id
            AND CAST(v.LastLinkARpmtDate AS DATE) > CAST(dateadd(day, - 45, getdate() AS DATE))
        )
    AND accountNum = '40728597'
    AND LastLinkARpmtDate BETWEEN @minDate
        AND @maxDate;
```

Comment: `AND CAST(v.LastLinkARpmtDate AS DATE) > CAST(dateadd(day, - 45, getdate() AS DATE))` ??  Should that not be written without the `CAST` (for performance reasons)?

Comment: It depends on whether your "dates" are actually DATETIMEs and your level of concern about when the script is run. If I use DATEADD to get 45 days ago, I'll get 45 days ago *at 9:33 AM*.  That means anything that happened before 9:30 will be left off. Up to you if that matters, but casting as DATE takes all values for that day. And yes, there's a performance hit, so depends on your data size and performance needs.

Answer (score 0):

The function dateadd() is what you need:

DATEADD (datepart , number , date)

Set @maxDate = DATEADD(DAY, -45, GETDATE());